# Is [optunity] a valid tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are 3 questions tagged [optunity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optunity):

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optunity

What is this for? Is 'optunity' even a word? Should it be cleaned up?

Comment: OK I found this:  http://optunity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Do you want to post your comment as an answer? Or to delete your question? Do you still suggest to remove the tag? It is unclear if you consider this question solved or not.

Comment: I dont know what should be done. Should I jusy make a tag wiki with that link and leave IT?

Comment: I'd say yes but we can wait to see if there are other opinions. Tag wiki excerpt would be good in any case. The lead developer of Optunity is our very own [@MarcClaesen](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/25433/marc-claesen), by the way.

Comment: Consider accepting @GeneralAbrial's answer, Kjetil, if you think it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should probably volunteer that I created the tag so that I could locate these particular posts among Marc's because they're useful to point to in questions about global optimization.

I justify this to myself in the same manner that I justified unilaterally making the Hauck-Donner Effect tag: these are questions that are thematically related but somewhat difficult to pin down in search unless you're a savant.

The community should override me if this is causing distress.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your having created a tag given the situation & your reasons. However, the tag has no wiki excerpt to guide usage. That isn't good. If you create a tag, you should (immediately) add an excerpt at a minimum (a full wiki would be nice too). Also, aren't you changing your name a bit much?

Comment: The name change thing is quite confusing indeed.

Comment: Fine, I'll revert my name -- or, at least, I will once I'm allowed to again.

Comment: Its up to you. At least this is pronounceable. I just find it curious, is all.

Comment: Thanks, I approved your edits, it awaits anther reviewer's approval to go through.

Comment: @Sycorax, would you mind taking a look at the discussion [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5082/7290), especially the bottom answer?